# MongoDB aggregation with $match and $group, $sum

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query the sum of an inner class. I put it together with what I've found on the internet but I am getting an empty response at the moment. Not quite sure what is wrong with it, since it's different parts that I've tried to put together.

I cannot create any custom classes and I can only use the @Aggregation method.

```
@Aggregation(" { $match:  { 'object':  $object, $and: [{'end': {$ne: null}}] } }, { '$group' : { 'object' : $object, 'object__price': { $sum: $object.price }}}")
    Integer sumPrices(@Param("$object") Object object);
```

(The names for the parameters are random in the code.)

I am trying to query for all items that match the object name and whose production value ('end') is not null. I then want to get the sum of all the objects of that types and return the sum value. Price value is an inner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@Aggregation(" { $match:  { 'object':  $object, $and: [{'end': {$ne: null}}] } }, { '$group' : { 'object' : $object, 'object__price': { $sum: "$price" }, count: {$sum: 1}}}")
```

" $sum: "$price" " would give the sum of key price of each document that falls in that object type, and count would give the total count of such documents